# Can I use LINQ to XML to extract the required date information from this XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Is this possible to achieve with LINQ to XML?

I have a `List<Congregation>` object and I obtain a list of all items where the last invited date is older than today:

```
var congs =_CongregationData.Congregations
                            .Where(a => a.LastInvited < DateTime.Today)
```

That's step 1. But then I have another XML file. Here is a cut down sample (ignore the dates as they are made up):

```
<AssignmentHistory>
    <W20230731>
        <PublicTalkInfo>
            <PublicTalkTheme>Theme 1</PublicTalkTheme>
        </PublicTalkInfo>
    </W20230731>
    <W20230807>
        <PublicTalkInfo>
            <PublicTalkTheme>Theme 2</PublicTalkTheme>
        </PublicTalkInfo>
    </W20230807>
    <W20230814>
        <PublicTalkInfo>
            <MeetingDate>2023-08-20</MeetingDate>
            <PublicTalkCongregation>Congregation 1</PublicTalkCongregation>
            <PublicTalkTheme>Theme 3</PublicTalkTheme>
        </PublicTalkInfo>
    </W20230814>
    <W20230821>
        <PublicTalkInfo>
            <MeetingDate>2023-08-27</MeetingDate>
            <PublicTalkCongregation>Congregation 2</PublicTalkCongregation>
            <PublicTalkTheme>Theme 4</PublicTalkTheme>
        </PublicTalkInfo>
    </W20230821>
    <W20230828>
        <PublicTalkInfo>
            <MeetingDate>2023-09-03</MeetingDate>
            <PublicTalkCongregation>Congregation 3</PublicTalkCongregation>
            <PublicTalkTheme>Theme 5</PublicTalkTheme>
        </PublicTalkInfo>
    </W20230828>
</AssignmentHistory>
```

I know that this XML is badly designed (with the `WYYYYMMDD` nodes all having different names) but this is the data file I must work with. Can I use LINQ to XML to obtain a set of records from this XML.

Eg,

```
for(var cong : congs)
{
    // 1. Select from history XML all records where PublicTalkCongregation is cong.Name.
    // 2. Records must be date descending on MeetingDate.
    // 3. We only want the records older than today.
}
```

To put it another way, can I use LINQ to XML to find the most recent date (`MeetingDate`) for `cong.Name` (`PublicTalkCongregation` ) that is prior to today. So that I can then update `cong.LastInvited` to this date.

Make sense?

---

#### Update

I am trying the proposed answer but getting exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: element
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.op_Explicit(XElement element)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.<>c.<Main>b__2_0(XElement x) in D:\My Programs\2022\Backup MSA2\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 24
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\My Programs\2022\Backup MSA2\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 23
```

I should clarify that some of the older assignment history entries won't have the `MeetingDate` \ `PublicTalkCongregation` elements which case those history weeks should be bypassed.

Comment: Your sample has the same W20230504 names for the nodes? And the same MeetingData values? Perhaps you should post a better sample (including having some empty entries)?

Comment: Your question doesn't have right details. You have to post more real xml string that includes all possible cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement assignments = doc.Descendants("AssignmentHistory").FirstOrDefault();
            List<Meeting> meetings = assignments.Elements().Select(x =>
                new Meeting()
                {
                    date = DateTime.ParseExact(x.Name.LocalName, "WyyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    meetingDate = x.Descendants("MeetingDate").FirstOrDefault() == null ? new DateTime() : (DateTime)x.Descendants("MeetingDate").FirstOrDefault(),          
                    congregation = (string)x.Descendants("PublicTalkCongregation").FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList();
 
        }
            
    }
   
}
public class Meeting
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public DateTime meetingDate { get; set; }
    public string congregation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try commenting out meetingDate to see if that is causing issue.  I updated with possible solution.  DateTime in c# cannot be null which I think is the issue.

Comment: I tested with no meeting date and code works.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your xml is very sloppy and so impossible to understand what do you want.

I would create a collection of data at first

```
    List<Meeting> meetings = XElement.Parse(xml)
              .Descendants("PublicTalkInfo")
              .Select(x => new Meeting
              {
                  MeetingDate = x.Element("MeetingDate")?.Value == null ?
                           null : DateTime.Parse(x.Element("MeetingDate").Value),
                  Congregation = x.Element("PublicTalkCongregation")?.Value
              }).ToList();

public class Meeting
{
    public DateTime? MeetingDate { get; set; }
    public string Congregation { get; set; }
}
```

after this I can use LINQ to extract any data I want, for example

```
    Meeting meeting = meetings.Where(x => x.Congregation != "To Be Confirmed")
                              .OrderBy(x => x.MeetingDate)
                              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the two provided answers, here is my final function (for sake of completeness).

```
public bool UpdateCongregationDatabase(string historyDatabase)
{
    bool bSaveDatabase = false;

    try
    {
        if (_Congregations.Count > 0)
        {
            var congregationsToReview = _Congregations
                        .Where(a => a.LastInvited < DateTime.Today);

            if(congregationsToReview.Count() > 0)
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(historyDatabase);
                List<Meeting> meetings = doc
                              .Descendants("PublicTalkInfo")
                              .Select(x => new Meeting
                              {
                                  MeetingDate = x.Element("MeetingDate")?.Value == null ?
                                           new DateTime() : DateTime.Parse(x.Element("MeetingDate").Value),
                                  Congregation = x.Element("PublicTalkCongregation")?.Value
                              }).ToList();

                if (meetings.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var congregation in congregationsToReview)
                    {
                        var historyForCongregation = meetings.Where(x => x.Congregation == congregation.Name && x.MeetingDate < DateTime.Today);
                        if (historyForCongregation.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            var lastInvitedMeeting = historyForCongregation.OrderByDescending(x => x.MeetingDate)
                                                                           .First();
                            if (lastInvitedMeeting != null &&
                                lastInvitedMeeting.MeetingDate > congregation.LastInvited)
                            {
                                congregation.LastInvited = (DateTime)lastInvitedMeeting.MeetingDate;
                                bSaveDatabase = true;
                            }
                        }

                        /*
                        var lastInvitedMeeting = meetings.Where(x => x.Congregation == congregation.Name && x.MeetingDate < DateTime.Today)
                                                         .OrderByDescending(x => x.MeetingDate)
                                                         .First();
                        if (lastInvitedMeeting != null)
                        {
                            congregation.LastInvited = (DateTime)lastInvitedMeeting.MeetingDate;
                            bSaveDatabase = true;
                        }
                        */
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
    }

    return bSaveDatabase;
}
```

I had to breakdown the post processing code to avoid exceptions. Not sure if that could be resolved.